# ASP.NET MVC Multiple Sequential Posts - Data Not Populating

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a fairly complex form on my ASP.NET MVC Page.  It works like this...

On default load (no HTTP post), it has two select boxes, bound to the Model, and a submit button.

On submit (HTTP post), the values in the select boxes are used to pull some data from the DB.  That data is then added to the model instance that was posted, and the instance is used to issue another View(myModelInstance) call.

At this point, things look good.  My select boxes retained the selected values, and the new elements based on the DB data are displaying.

If I do another post now, whether I change data or not, the original values selected in the select boxes are null within the Action method of my controller, but the values for the DB data textboxes are not.

The only thing I am really doing special here is using the index notation within Razor to be able to edit parts of my Model that are within an IEnumerable...as in the following example...

```
@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.SomeArbitraryNumber; i++)
{
     <input type="text" name="myModel.MyEnumerable[@i].MyValue" 
            value="@(Model.MyEnumerable[i].MyValue)" size="2" />
}
```

This indexed notation usage only happens after the original select box values have been posted.

**UPDATE:**
It seems that the major contributor here is the special index notation.  If I eliminate it, it works fine.  Also, if I include additional hidden fields to match the two select boxes, and also use the indexed notation for those, the second post works.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your browser is caching the original select boxes, and they were never populated by your second view? In MVC you have to populate the select boxes every time they are displayed. In Webforms, viewstate does this for you automagically, but in MVC it is up to you to make sure they are populated.

Comment: Yeah, I am populating them in both the standard View and the HttpPost view.  I can also see in the source that the values are there.  They just don't seem to be hydrated into the model on the second post.